# (C++/Python) Capture window screenshot without caret indicator

Tags: python, c++, winapi, window

I want to capture the screenshot of the existing running window via Python.
Following is my sample code for capture Notepad window:

```
import time
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
import pyautogui


def getWindowScreenshot(hwnd, output_file):
    r = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    width = r[2] - r[0]
    height = r[3] - r[1]
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # save the bitmap to a file
    dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, output_file)

    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    window_title = "Untitled - Notepad"
    winHandle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
    if winHandle == 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Window '{window_title}' is not opening!")

    # Bring the window to foreground in case it is overlap by other windows
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(winHandle)
    # Do something with Notepad
    time.sleep(3)

    # Capture the window
    getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output.bmp")
```

However, sometimes the captured image will have the blinking caret indicator on the input textbox.
[image]

My question is, how to capture the screenshot without getting the caret indicator?

I already tried some solution, but not suitable:

**Solution 1:**

```
# Bring the window to foreground in case it is overlap by other windows
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(winHandle)
    # Do something with Notepad
    time.sleep(3)

    # Make the "Desktop window" focus
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow())

    # Capture the window
    getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output.bmp")
```

Before capturing the screenshot, try to set "Desktop" as the foreground window.
However, the command `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow())` will raise an error:

```
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')
```

**Solution 2:**

Replace `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow())` with `win32gui.ShowWindow(winHandle, 4)`, where `4` is `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`.
The code run OK, but the Notepad window doesn't lose focus after execution.

**Solution 3:**

```
# Bring the window to foreground in case it is overlap by other windows
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(winHandle)
    # Do something with Notepad
    time.sleep(3)

    # Click outside of window
    r = win32gui.GetWindowRect(winHandle)
    pyautogui.click(r[2]+1, r[3]+1)

    # Capture the window
    getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output.bmp")
```

With this solution, I tried to click outside the Notepad window (click on the desktop). This code seems worked, but will not work if another window is behind the Notepad window like this:

[image]

When the code is executed, it will click on the Windows Explorer window. So, the code can perform clicking on something unexpectedly (example: deleting the system file unexpectedly?).

**Solution 4**
(from @SongZhu-MSFT)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    window_title = "Untitled - Notepad"
    winHandle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
    if winHandle == 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Window '{window_title}' is not opening!")

    # Bring the window to foreground in case it is overlap by other windows
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(winHandle)
    # Do something with Notepad
    time.sleep(3)

    win32gui.EnableWindow(winHandle,False)
    # Capture the window
    getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output.bmp")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output1.bmp")
    time.sleep(5)
    win32gui.EnableWindow(winHandle,True)
```

When I run the code, I still see that the caret displaying all time.
And `output.bmp` + `output1.bmp` still exists one image with the caret.

System information:

- Windows 10 1909
- Python 3.7.9

Comment: I believe the correct term is "Focus"; maybe you can use `win32gui.SetFocus(0)` or something like that?

Comment: @anatolyg, I tried `win32gui.SetFocus(0)` but it still not working. The Notepad window is still under focus.

Comment: [HideCaret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-hidecaret), followed by a call to [ShowCaret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcaret).

Comment: @IInspectable, I tried `win32gui.HideCaret(winHandle)` but it throw error `pywintypes.error: (5, 'HideCaret', 'Access is denied.')`. Do you have any idea with this problem? I tried run PyCharm with Administrator mode but still not working

Comment: I tested the code, and it seems that the caret appears when the window is clicked. Maybe you can use `win32gui.EnableWindow(winHandle,False)` and call `win32gui.EnableWindow(winHandle,True)` after the capture is over

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT, after a call to `win32gui.EnableWindow(winHandle,False)`, I still see that the caret is displaying in Notepad screen. Did the code work on your side?

Comment: Yes, the code works for me. Is there any other operation that caused the caret to exist while you were capturing the window? (e.g. click)

Comment: After call to `win32gui.EnableWindow(winHandle,False)`, I will call to `getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output.bmp")` immediately, no click action between them. I also don't know what is different

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT, I updated my post, added `Solution 4` for the full code based on your solution,

Comment: Try to call `EnableWindow` before sleep, like:  `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(winHandle)
    win32gui.EnableWindow(winHandle,False)
    time.sleep(3)`

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT, I tried calling as you said, but it still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my test, I can use `SendMessageW` to send `WM_KILLFOCUS` to make the caret disappear.

This is the code that worked for me:

```
import time
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
import pyautogui
from ctypes import windll

def getWindowScreenshot(hwnd, output_file):
    r = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    width = r[2] - r[0]
    height = r[3] - r[1]
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # save the bitmap to a file
    dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, output_file)

    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    window_title = "Untitled - Notepad"
    winHandle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
    if winHandle == 0:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Window '{window_title}' is not opening!")

    # Bring the window to foreground in case it is overlap by other windows
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(winHandle)
    # Do something with Notepad
    windll.user32.SendMessageW(winHandle, win32con.WM_KILLFOCUS, None, None)
    # Capture the window
    getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output.bmp")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    getWindowScreenshot(winHandle, "output1.bmp")
```

Comment: `SendMessageW (WM_KILLFOCUS)` worked for me too. Thank you!